# Unable to lock firefox.desktop file to dock

Tags: unity, unity-dash, gdm

I created a .Desktop file for Firefox (I downloaded the nightly version from their website). Here is the file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Nightly
Comment=This is the nightly entry ie firefox entry
Exec=/opt/firefox/./firefox
Icon=/opt/firefox/icons/logo.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Accessories;
GenericName[en_IN]=this should start firefox
```

I placed this file on `.local/share/applicaitons` to search from the dock. But whenever I launch the application and right click on the icon that appeared on the dock, it dosen't give me the option to lock the application to favorites only allows me to Quit or display all windows. I am using `GDM3`.

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version? Are you using Unity?

Comment: Ubuntu version 17 and yes I am using Unity. @pomsky

Comment: 17.10 or 17.04?

Comment: 17.0.4, I don't mean to be offensive at all, but will such marginal version difference cause any problems. @pomsky

Comment: 17.04 is end of life, and hence [off-topic here](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Your Exec= line could be cleaner, i.e `Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox` At least here the icon for ff nightly in /opt is `/opt/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default48.png`  This works fine here, what did you name the .desktop file you placed in .local/share/applicaitons? (here I use `ff-nightly.desktop`

Comment: **Warning for VTD: OP has found a solution** It would be beneficial to re-open this question so they can post the answer themselves.

Comment: Reviewers: As @Fabby says, the OP found a solution (see [the revision history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1025498/revisions)) and, based on that, I think the problem doesn't look at all specific to 17.04. Under the circumstances, I agree with reopening this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what's worked for me, I went into the `/usr/share/applications/` directory where the original `firefox-esr.desktop` file is kept (which was indeed locked to the dash.), Replace the `Exec` value in the original file with the path of your firefox executable.

```
vim firefox-esr
Exec=/opt/firefox/./firefox
```

and now you have a dash icon for your upgraded firefox (nightly) entry.